# Pandas - Function to remove na

Tags: python, pandas

trying to do a quick function but struggling since new to Pandas/Python. I'm trying to remove nas from two of my columns, but I keep getting this error, my code is the following:

```
def remove_na():
    df.dropna(subset=['Column 1', 'Column 2'])
    df.reset_index(drop=True)

df = remove_rows()
df.head(3)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

I want to use this function on different tables, hence why I thought it would make sense to create a method. However, I just don't understand why it's not working for this method when compared to others it seems fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can specify if you want to remove NA from columns or rows by the paremeter axis where 0 is index and 1 is columns. This would remove all NAs from all columns

```
df.dropna(axis =1, inplace=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use apply with dropna:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print (df)
```

OR you can also try this

```
df=df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error cos the **dropna** function here yields a dataframe as its output.
You can either save it to a dataframe:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Column 1', 'Column 2'])
```

or call the argument '`inplace=True`' :

```
df.dropna(subset=['Column 1', 'Column 2'], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove all the missing values from the data set at once using pandas  you can use the following:(Remember You have to specify the index  in the arguments so that you can efficiently remove the missing values)

```
# making new data frame with dropped NA values 
 new_data = data.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
```